# Flutter input field collapsed when showing error message

Tags: flutter, dart, textformfield

I was add 2 input field in the same row in the mobile screen input fields are collapsed when showing error.

```
Row(
children: <Widget>[
  Expanded(
      flex: 2,
      child: TextFormField(
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode
            .onUserInteraction,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        controller: controller.plz,
        validator: ValidationBuilder(
                localeName: localeLanguage)
            .digits()
            .minLength(5)
            .required()
            .build(),
        decoration: inputdecoration(),
      )),
  SizedBox(width: 10.0),
  Expanded(
      flex: 3,
      child: TextFormField(
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode
            .onUserInteraction,
        validator: ValidationBuilder(
                localeName: localeLanguage)
            .required()
            .build(),
        controller: controller.place,
        decoration: inputdecoration(),
      ))
],
),
```

InputDecoration(
errorMaxLines: 3,
helperText: '',
contentPadding:
new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
fillColor: AsianmastaColors.white,
filled: true,
border: OutlineInputBorder(
borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0)))

//after showing error
n[image]ew
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to read the code. First update your question adding the code on code block. You will find {} symbol just above the text pad.

Answer (score 0):

give the Row crossAxisAlignment.start and it will work

```
Row(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start
children: <Widget>[
Expanded(
  flex: 2,
  child: TextFormField(
    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode
        .onUserInteraction,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    controller: controller.plz,
    validator: ValidationBuilder(
            localeName: localeLanguage)
        .digits()
        .minLength(5)
        .required()
        .build(),
    decoration: inputdecoration(),
  )),
  SizedBox(width: 10.0),
  Expanded(
  flex: 3,
  child: TextFormField(
    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode
        .onUserInteraction,
    validator: ValidationBuilder(
            localeName: localeLanguage)
        .required()
        .build(),
    controller: controller.place,
    decoration: inputdecoration(),
  ))
],
),
```